# Unable to style JTextPane and display HTML images together

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, styleddocument

I have been using a JTextPane to display basic HTML content including locally saved images. I have been trying to style the JTextPane using the text pane's input attributes. Whenever I modify the styling of the pane, the HTML images I have break and won't appear without commenting out the styling code.

This is an SSCE of the code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.MutableAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit;

public class JTextPaneImageTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JTextPaneImageTest();
    }

    public JTextPaneImageTest() {
        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setContentType("text/html");
        textPane.setEditable(false);

        String content = "<html><body><p>Test text here</p>"
                + "<img src=\"file:\\\\\\C:\\Users\\racha_000\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\ebookr\\test.jpg\" />"
                + "</body></html>";
        System.out.println(content);

        HTMLEditorKit editorKit = (HTMLEditorKit) textPane.getEditorKit();
        HTMLDocument htmlDoc = (HTMLDocument) textPane.getDocument();
        MutableAttributeSet mats = textPane.getInputAttributes();
        StyleConstants.setForeground(mats, Color.RED);

        try {
            editorKit.insertHTML(htmlDoc, htmlDoc.getLength(), content, 0, 0, null);
        } catch (BadLocationException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            htmlDoc.setCharacterAttributes(0, htmlDoc.getLength(), mats, true);
        }

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(textPane);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The important code to note is that whenever the mutable attribute set is changed and the character attributes set, the images don't work.

```
MutableAttributeSet mats = textPane.getInputAttributes();
StyleConstants.setForeground(mats, Color.RED);
htmlDoc.setCharacterAttributes(0, htmlDoc.getLength(), mats, true);
```

Without styling:

[image: Without Styling]

With styling:

[image: With Styling]

Styling the document this way has been the only method that has worked for me as I insert the content all at once as HTML and style it all the same way. Other methods haven't worked, so I'm hoping to be able to maintain this method of styling the panel.

Comment: is the setCharacterAttributes() method called several times in your real program, or just once ? Setting its last argument to false resolves the problem in the SSCE.

Comment: @vip It's only called once, tried it in the real program and it works. Thank you very much, I hadn't even thought about that arg.

Comment: OK I write a formal answer then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling the `setCharacterAttributes()` method with its last argument (*replace*) to `true` somewhat erases HTML code related to your image.

Simply call it with `false` and it works:

```
htmlDoc.setCharacterAttributes(0, htmlDoc.getLength(), mats, false);
```

[image: image displayed with styled text]